# Django's jinja like block feature in ejs

Tags: node.js, django, django-templates, ejs

I have a node-express project that have several page in it, I use ejs templating engine and currently how I handled base-template is copy-paste the template html to new page (Basically, it's bad)

I want to use django's jinja 'block' like feature in ejs, is there that kind of feature in ejs? (I confused by ejs website)

Is there a way to use base-template in ejs OR is there a templating engine that you recommend that have base-template feature in it OR  should I stay with my current implementation of copy-pasting base-template?

Comment: Searched through ejs documentation found that ejs doesn't support block like jinja does. It would have been great if block feature is added in ejs. [![ejs documentation screenshot mentioning that it doesn't support block like in jinja](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgDAr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgDAr.png)